# <mark> Html tag not working while rendering Html to pdf

Tags: html, css, django, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

I am generating a pdf from the html page . The mark highlighting tag was working fine in the html page but when i render to pdf the mark tag is not working but other css and html tag are working fine.

My html code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Report</title>
<style>
div.long-text{
 max-width:100%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 padding: 1rem;
 }
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
}
p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
body, input {
  margin: 5;
  font: .9em Verdana, 'Lucida Grande', Geneva, Lucida, sans-serif;
  }
</style>
</head>
 <body>
<div>
  {% for i in text %}
  {% if i.0 == '0'%}
       <mark>{{i}}</mark>
    {% else %}
      {{i}}
     {% endif %}
    {% endfor%}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is like this:

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Please help figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alternate `mark`
Instead of mark, you can use `<span>`

```
<span>{{ i }} </span>
```

Then in the CSS part

```
span { 
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```